# Is there a way to let textarea not show CSS transform when resize it?

Tags: html, css, textarea

When I was going to set background transition of the `<textarea>` on hover, it succeed. However, when I tried to resize it, the `transition` time still works.

Here is my code, and you can drag the `<textarea>` to see what's wrong:

```css
textarea::-webkit-resizer:active {
  transition:0s;
}
textarea:hover{
  background:rgb(200,200,200);
}


textarea{
  transition:1s;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

I am looking for a way to let it do not perform the transition when I drag it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue can be addressed by specifying which CSS property to transition to, and in this case, specifying the background-color should do the trick:

```css
textarea::-webkit-resizer:active {
  transition: 0s;
}

textarea:hover {
  background: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

textarea {
  transition: background-color 1s;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

You can learn more about the transition and its shorthand from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition)